# when inserting data into sqlserver showing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am creating application in MVC. When I am trying to insert data into SQL Server 2008 it shows error like the following:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The existing object is in the Unchanged state. An object can only be
>   added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state.

What does this mean?

```
      Candidate candidate = _repository.GetCandidate(LoggedInCandidate.Id);

            candidate.Name = collection["Name"];
            candidate.Email = collection["Email"];
            candidate.Address = collection["Address"];
            candidate.ContactNumber = collection["ContactNumber"];
            candidate.MobileNumber = collection["MobileNumber"];
            candidate.LicenseNumber = collection["LicenseNumber"];
            int candidateId = _repository.AddCandidate(candidate);
            string[] languages = collection["Languages"].Split(',');
         foreach (string language in languages)
         {
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
             {
                 CandidateLanguage cl = new CandidateLanguage();
                 cl.CandidateId = candidateId;
                 cl.LanguageId = Convert.ToInt32(language);
                 _repository.AddCandidateLanguage(cl);
             }
         }

           _repository.Save();
           }
```

Comment: It means that an entity of the same type and with the same Id has already been loaded into the context and duplicates are not allowed. We need to see some code to be able to tell what exactly leads to this.

Comment: Please show us your controller code where you insert into the database and call db.SaveChanges()

Answer (score 0):

You already get a candidate with a id. Why do you insert this candidate again into context???

If you want to insert a new candidate, why do you create a new candidate and insert it.

Comment: I have a method in repository for GetCandidate(). Just I call this function. I inserted CandidateId for get the candidateId from the database and stores the other values in the same Id. I dont know why it shows an error.

Comment: If you want to store other values of the candidate that you get, you only update this candidate.

Comment: I correct it.Thanks for your comment. I assign the candidateId to candidate.id. Then it is added.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to duplicate existing entity and just modify some properties after that you will need a copy constructor ( or something with a similar idea ) and then insert the new entity into db.

If you want to modify your current candidate you'll do

```
        Candidate candidate = _repository.GetCandidate(LoggedInCandidate.Id);

        candidate.Name = collection["Name"];
        candidate.Email = collection["Email"];
        candidate.Address = collection["Address"];
        candidate.ContactNumber = collection["ContactNumber"];
        candidate.MobileNumber = collection["MobileNumber"];
        candidate.LicenseNumber = collection["LicenseNumber"];

        _repository.Entry(candidate).State = EntityState.Modified;

        ....

        _repository.Save();
```